# Javascript calling in variables from HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the javascript portion working (cut off bottom portion of it to reduce code length) when I manually put in the numbers however, I'm struggling with putting my javascript together with my html. I tried stealing bits of code to get it to work, ultimately I'd like to just have one button that says "Get Pricing" that passes the 4 variables quantity, colors, logoSheet, and margin to the respective javascript variables.

```
        <form>
    <br>
            <label id="_quantity" >Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" id="quantity" maxlength="254" data-hint="" name="quantity" required/>
    <br>
            <label id="_colors" ># of Colors</label>
            <input type="number" id="colors" maxlength="254" data-hint="" name="colors" required/>
    <br>            
            <label id="_logoSheet" ># Logo's per Sheet</label>
            <input type="number" id="logoSheet" maxlength="254" data-hint="" name="logoSheet" required/>
    <br>            
            <label id="_margin" >Margin %</label>
            <input type="number" id="margin" maxlength="254" data-hint="" name="margin" required/>

<br>
            <input type="submit" class="fb-button-special" id="fb-submit-button" value="submit" />

        </form>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Pricing</button>
<p>Total Shirt Only:</p> <p id="totalShirtOnly"></p>
<p>Total Sheet Cost:</p> <p id="totalSheetCost"></p>
<p>Price Per Sheet:</p> <p id="costOfSheets"></p>
<p>Total Price:</p> <p id="totalPrice"></p>
<p>Net Profit:</p> <p id="netProfit"></p>

</center>


<script>
function myFunction()
{


var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity.value');
var colors = document.getElementById('colors.value');
var logoSheet = document.getElementById('logoSheet.value');
var margin = document.getElementById('margin.value');


var shirtCost = 2.43;
var sheetShipping = 15.0;

var marginPercent = margin/100;

var totalCost = 0.0;
var costOfSheets = 0.0;


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which JavaScript variables you're referring to and if you're using jQuery or not but here's how to get values of HTML elements:

```
// With jQuery
var colors = $("#colors").val();

// w/o jQuery
var margin = document.getElementById("margin").value
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I was putting the .value inside the "" and that was messing me up